# Git fetch notes after forced push on the remote

Tags: git

I am finding a lot of answers to how to make a local branch look like a remote branch, but in my case, I need to take in changes that were force pushed to the remote to `refs/notes/commits`.

The changes were made using `git notes add`. The remote was updated using `git push origin refs/notes/* -f`.

I have different history for `refs/notes/commits` locally. Until now I was using `git fetch origin "refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*"` to integrate remote notes changes to my local. With the forced push, the two histories are now disjoint. I want to throw away mine and take in theirs.

Since `refs/notes/commits` is not a branch (right?) I cannot use `git push` or `git checkout` to enter it and then `git reset` (again, right?). So, what can I use to make my local `refs/notes*` equivalent to the remote `refs/notes/*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that `refs/notes/commits` is not a *branch*, as all branch names by definition start with `refs/heads/` instead.  However, `git fetch` and `git push` work with *any* ref-name, and you can force-fetch as well as force-push.  So:

> Until now I was using `git fetch origin "refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*"` to integrate remote notes changes to my local. With the forced push, the two histories are now disjoint. I want to throw away mine and take in theirs.

That would be a forced fetch.  To force a fetch, do the same thing you do with `git push`: add the `--force` flag, or prefix the *refspec*—the pair of names separated by a colon—with a plus sign.  The latter is shorter (by at least one character) so that's the one I'll use here:<sup>1</sup>

```
git fetch origin "+refs/notes/*:refs/notes/*"
```

or:

```
git fetch origin "+refs/notes/commits:refs/notes/commits"
```

This will overwrite the current value (stored hash ID) of your `refs/notes/commits` with the fetched value, provided they have a `refs/notes/commits`; the variant with `*` will overwrite *all* of your `refs/notes/` names with theirs (creating any names they have that you didn't before).

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `+` in front of a refspec sets the force flag for *that one refspec*, while `--force` on the command line sets the force flag for *all* refspecs.  That is:

```
git fetch origin refs/heads/br1:refs/heads/br1 +refs/heads/br2:refs/heads/br2
```

fetches from origin's branch `br1` to (local) branch `br1` without forcing, but fetches from origin's `br2` to `br2` *with* forcing.  Compare with:

```
git fetch --force origin refs/heads/br1:refs/heads/br1 refs/heads/br2:refs/heads/br2
```

which forces both updates.  A *forced update* simply takes place even if Git's normal rules would reject the update.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>2</sup>For `git push`, the other end can add *additional, non-Git rules*.  That's how GitHub and others provide "protected branches", for instance.  Since these are not Git's normal rules, the `--force` or `+` flag does not override *these* rules.  There's nothing equivalent for `git fetch`, since that's into *your own* repository and you are assumed to know what you are doing.